# GIT: corrupt files don't allow me to checkout other branch

Tags: git

I think the problem started when I was testing a feature in one branch and my pc crashed.
When I booted my pc again, git started showing me some messages of the type "error: object file .git/objects/... is empty" and "fatal: loose object ... (stored in .git/objects/...) is corrupt" whenever I try to check out other branch or check the git status or git log.

I have some files on a different branch that I haven't pushed to any remote repository.
Do you have any idea how can I recover them?

Comment: What errors are reported by `git fsck` ?

Comment: @LeGEC "error: object file .git/objects/... is empty", "error: unable to mmap .git/objects/...: No such file or directory", "error: object file .git/objects/... is empty" and 
"fatal: loose object ... (stored in .git/objects/...) is corrupt"

Comment: Does `git rev-parse different/branch` work (and prints a 40 char long hash), or does it trigger an error ?

Comment: Yes, it works. It prints a hash like you said.